# Downgrading Python Setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, pyinstaller

I am getting an error while attempting to use Pyinstaller. After doing some research I believe the error is caused by a bug in the most recent version of setuptools (19.3). The fix seems to be downgrading to setuptools version 19.2. My issue is with the downgrade itself. My question is how does one downgrade setuptools in Ubuntu 15.04?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just specify the version using `pip`:

```
pip install setuptools==19.2
```

If you are installing globally you will obviously need sudo.

```
~$ sudo pip install setuptools==19.2
Collecting setuptools==19.2
Downloading setuptools-19.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (463kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 466kB 486kB/s 
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 19.1
    Uninstalling setuptools-19.1:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-19.1
Successfully installed setuptools-19.2
~$ sudo pip install setuptools==19.1 
Collecting setuptools==19.1
  Downloading setuptools-19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (463kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 466kB 377kB/s 
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 19.2
    Uninstalling setuptools-19.2:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-19.2
Successfully installed setuptools-19.1
```